# JProfiler inherent time

Tags: jvm-hotspot, jprofiler

The hotspots view (cpu view) shows incorrect time units for inherent times. I tried profiling an application which copies a physical file 200 times concurrently. The application completed in 1.2 seconds while the jprofiler snapshot shows a particular method taking 122 secs. That's strange.

[image: Here is a snapshot sample]

Anyone who has worked with jprofiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks OK. JProfiler shows elapsed times, not CPU times. By default, the CPU views cumulate all threads, so with 200 concurrent threads, the displayed time measurements should be upwards of 200 times of the time measurements for a single thread.

You can use the thread selector at the top to switch to a single thread, then you will see times that correspond to the total run time.